# Question about predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I know how to represent the sentence “there is exactly one person that is happy”,

∀y∀x((Happy(x)∧Happy(y))→(x=y))

Edit: ∃x∀y(y=x↔Happy(y))
(NOW, I actually know how to represent it)

Where x and y represent a person.

However, my problem is that I can’t figure out how to say “there are exactly 3 people that are happy” in predicate logic.

Comment: Wrong... $\exists x [H(x) \land \forall y(H(y) \to x=y)]$

Comment: Apparently you *don't*: your first-order sentence says "At most one person is happy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to represent the sentence “there is exactly one person that is happy”: $$∀y∀x((\text{Happy}(x)∧\text{Happy}(y))→(x=y))$$

Correction: $$∃x \,∀p\;\Big( p=x \leftrightarrow\text{Happy}(p) \Big).$$

(Note that even though this sentence looks simpler than Tom's suggestion, they are actually logically equivalent to each other.)

> I can’t figure out how to say “there are exactly 3 people that are happy” in predicate logic.

$$∃x ∃y ∃z \,∀p\;\bigg(x\neq y\land y\neq z\land z\neq x  \land \Big( (p=x\lor p=y\lor p=z ) \leftrightarrow\text{Happy}(p)  \Big)\bigg).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! But I am confused about one thing, don’t we need to first establish that x is happy?

Comment: Do you mean my first sentence? It reads as "For some person $x,$ 1) every person who is $x$ is happy, and 2) every happy person is $x$"; this implicitly claims that person $x$ exists and is happy, i.e., that person $x$ is happy. Click [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#~7x~6p(p=x~4Hp)~4(~7x(Hx~1~6p(Hp~5p=x)))) for a proof that Tom's suggestion and mine are indeed equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the proof! Besides, this seems like an incredibly useful website.  But I am still confused about 1 thing, in the first sentence, which part states that “every person who is x is happy”? Is it “Happy(p)”?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! $\;∀p\Big( p=x \to\text{Happy}(p) \Big)$ reads as "for every person, if they are $x,$ then they are happy", i.e., "every person who is $x$ is happy".

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually asserted that anyone *is* happy. So, You need to introduce a happy person, and then assert that anyone else who is happy is actually that person:
$$\exists x\left(\mathrm{Happy}(x)\wedge\left(\forall y\left(\mathrm{Happy}(y)\to (y=x)\right)\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

You can extend this simply as: if 4 people are happy then at least one is equal to the other.
$\forall x,y,z,w((Happy(x)\land Happy(y) \land Happy(z) \land Happy(w))\rightarrow(x=y \lor x=z \lor x=w \lor y=z \lor y=w \lor z=w)) \land \exists x,y,z (Happy(x)\land Happy(y) \land Happy(z) \land x\neq y \land y\neq z \land x \neq z) $